# Support for FDB driver in SQLObject

Tags: python, firebird, fdb

Does anybody know if there are any support for the new FDB driver in SQLObject, as far as I can tell it only supports the outdated kinterbasedb.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can replace kinterbasdb with fdb in the driver and most of the things should work

https://gist.github.com/mariuz/6591253

Please run the tests and check the changes in the driver vs kinterbasdb

http://pythonhosted.org/fdb/differences-from-kdb.html

I recommend also SQL Alchemy it does support fdb driver and seems to be more tested
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/firebird.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.firebird.fdb